# What is a widget container?

Tags: web-applications

I have searched about this on the net, but have not been able to find a good explanation.

What is a widget container, why is it used?

Answer (score 1):

Widget containers are essentially a software abstraction. They used to manage a whole lot of widgets together. As an example, the editor we use here in stack overflow for asking questions and answering them, can be considered as a widget container. It contains several widgets which work together. Some of these widgets are buttons like B I etc, some are text areas.